# Filling OER with data from an xml

Tags: xml, oracle, oracle11g

I need to Fill OER(Oracle Enterprise Repository) with a huge amount of data stored in an XML,my question is does anyone know how to do this via the visual interface? or i have to create an XML to XML converter in order to store this information in the OER from import/export option?

I have seen this documentation:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/doc.1111/e16581/install.htm#OERQS109 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28369/xdb_web_services.htm#CHDDBCHB

Comment: Hello Nicolas. My answer is helpfull for you? If yes, please vote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java REX api.

With this API you can create assets, list values, categorizations, etc...

You can see how to in [this manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/doc.1111/e15754/overview.htm#OERIN319)

If you have dudes in how to use REX please make me questions.